# $h(x,y)$ harmonic with conjugate harmonic conjugate $g(x,y)$. Show $\log(f(x,y)) = \log(h(x,y)^2 + g(x,y)^2)$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I have the following question

> Suppose that $h(x,y)$, with no zeros in $\mathbb{D}$ with harmonic with conjugate harmonic conjugate $g(x,y)$. Show $f(x,y) = \log(h(x,y)^2 + g(x,y)^2)$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{D}$.

The question says that you are not meant to calculate a bunch of partial derivatives. Thus, I think that you are suppose to express $f$ has a real or imaginary of an analytic function in $\mathbb{D}$. We can write

$$k(x + iy) = h(x,y) + i v(x,y)$$

where $k$ is analytic (and nonzero) in $\mathbb{D}$. Since $k$ is analytic in $\mathbb{D}$, nonzero, and $\mathbb{D}$ is simply connected, we can define a branch of $\log(k^2)$. I am wondering if I can say that $\log(k^2) = \log|k| + i \arg(k^2)$ and then conclude that $f$ is harmonic since $\log|k| =  f(x,y)$. I am not sure if I am allowed to express $\log(k^2)$ is this form.

Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $f$, and what does it have to do with $h$ and $g$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich There was a typo, it should say $f(x,y) = \log(h(x,y)^2 + g(x,y)^2)$

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: @zhw Why is not clear? I am asked to show that $\log(g(x,y)^2 + h(x,y)^2)$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: So *“Show $f(x,y) = \log(h(x,y)^2 + g(x,y)^2)$ in $\mathbb{D}$”* should be *“Show that $f(x,y) = \log(h(x,y)^2 + g(x,y)^2)$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{D}$”* ?

Comment: It's not clear because you never _said_ that you wanted to show that $f$ was harmonic.

Comment: $F=h+ig$, $F$ analytic and non zero in the disc, so $\log F$ is analytic and $\Re \log F$ harmonic; but $\Re \log F=\log |F|=1/2\log |F|^2=1/2\log (h^2+g^2)$ so you are done

Comment: @Conrad Okay, can you write $\log k^2 = \log|k|^2 + i \arg k^2$ as I have written in my question? Why is it that $\re \log F = \log|F|$?

Comment: sure $k^2$ is analytic and non-zero, so you can do it that way; not sure about second question as it is obvious from $\log F=\log |F|+i \arg F$ that $\Re \log F=\log |F|, \Im \log F =\arg F$ (where $\arg$ is an analytic argument obtained by analytic continuation usually so it may or may not coincide with the principal branch at a given value